# kendo grid doesn't react to changes if cell's (which is kendoDropDownList) value is empty string

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid which is editable `(editable: "incell")`. One of it's fields is editable with kendoDropDownList. When I edit it's value grid reacts to changes and row gets updated. However if value is empty string then it doesn't.

kendoDropDownList itself does react to changes. I added 'change' callback to it and it kicks in.

How can I manually force grid to update row from within kendoDropDownList's 'change' callback?

Answer (score 0):

You can go from dropdown to parent tr to get rownumber. 
After that you can do something like:

```
     var value = drop down value
     var i = Get row index....
     var data = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();     
     data[i].YourField= value;   
     $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

Comment: thanks, I'll check it. It looks like workaround but it should work.